# completing a primitive integer vector into an integer matrix of determinant 1

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, determinant

This is probably well known in algebraic number theory, in particular Minkowski lattice theory, but I am given an integer vector of dimension $n$ whose components are relatively prime, meaning there is an integer linear combination of them that equals 1. Is it true that I can always find $n-1$ other integer vectors such that they form an element of $SL(n, \mathbb{Z})$? I tried to think in terms of cofactor expansion of determinant, but that was only useful for $n=2$. Thinking geometrically also bore no fruit. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: This is a particular case of [Smith normal form](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form) theorem.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. With further help of TedShifrin I got it finally. So we apply the Smith normal form to a n x 1 matrix, using product of elementary matrices P and Q, which both have determinant +/-1. Then $P'Q'$ would give the desired extension.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the construction of such a basis in M. Newman's book "[Integral Matrices](https://books.google.com/books/about/Integral_Matrices.html?id=jEKFYutSGGYC&printsec=frontcover&source=kp_read_button#v=onepage&q=completion%20to%20a%20unimodular&f=false)". It's Theorem II.$1$ on Page 13.